# Iterate with ngFor on objects obtained from Firebase

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, object

I have a list of objects stored in firebase database:
[image: Screenshot from firebase console]

I am getting this list using angular http get request. After getting it I want to iterate on a li in html template using `ngFor="let subject of subjects"` which gives Error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

As I searched online, I came to know that ngFor can only be used on arrays while I am getting nested objects. Can anyone please suggest me what should I do iterate these objects.

So far I have tried `Array.of` which converts whole list into `someArray[0]`. I also tried to manually change the unique ids of objects into array indexes `[0, 1, 2]` which worked but when I add new subject using `http post` firebase automatically assigns unique id to new subject making it uniteratable.

In simple words tell me to convert nested objects into an arrayList or how can I change the firebase default behavior of assigning unique id in angular (I found something like firebase push function which I couldn't understand).

Update:

(Code from ExaminerService)

```
getBatchSubjects(batch){
        return this.http.get(firebaseLinkGoesHere);
    }
```

(Code from Component)

```
onBatchSelected(event){
    this.selectedBatch = event.target.value; //getting value of a html select
      this.examinerService.getBatchSubjects(this.selectedBatch)
      .subscribe(
        (response : Response) => {
          this.selectedBatchData = response.json();
        }
      ),(error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
  }
```

(Code from HTML Template)

```
<div class="batchDetails">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">S.No</th>
        <th>Subject Name</th>
        <th>Facilitator</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let subject of selectedBatchData.subjects; let i = index">
        <td class="text-center"> {{i + 1}} </td>
        <td> {{subject.name}} </td>
        <td> {{subject.facilitator}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing mustache!

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad, Can you please help me solve this issue? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to turn the properties into an array. This can be done in several ways.

**Method 1** - By applying the [map operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) to the observable data (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkyo5f)):

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

public subjects: Array<any>;

this.examinerService.getBatchSubjects(this.selectedBatch)
  .map(x => (Object as any).values(x.json().subjects))
  .subscribe(
    (values) => { this.subjects = values; },
    (error) => { console.log(error); }
  );
```

**Method 2** - With a property getter or a method of the component class (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjwcje)):

```
get subjects(): Array<any> {
  return (Object as any).values(this.selectedBatchData.subjects);
}
```

**Method 3** - By converting the values in the subscribe callback (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzajmm)):

```
public subjects: Array<any>;
...

this.selectedBatchData = response.json();
this.subjects = (Object as any).values(this.selectedBatchData.subjects);
```

---

**Template**

In the template, the `ngFor` directive would iterate over the `subjects` array:

```
<tr *ngFor="let subject of subjects; let i = index">
  <td class="text-center"> {{i + 1}} </td>
  <td> {{subject.name}} </td>
  <td> {{subject.facilitator}} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Man you are awesome. Thank you so much. I am finding this solution since whole day.

Comment: You are welcome. I added a method to do it with the `map` operator.

Comment: You don't need the `as any`. `Array <any>` is also bad.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - It may work without it but the syntax checker in Visual Studio Code and in stackblitz underlines `Object.values` in red ("Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'"), and I don't like to see that.

Comment: That means you neglected to set `--lib es2017` or `--lib esnext` (more generally it means you have a polyfill that you have not declared). You are suppressing all errors by using a type assertion to `any`. This is incorrect and it will bite you.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Can you please tell me why using `as any` is a bad idea, and what side effects it can have and in which conditions? :)

Comment: @RobertWilliams  it disables error checking, intellisense, and all other reasons that you use TypeScript in the first place.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yup that I understand that's why I tried to set any other :dataType but it gives error on all of them like cant assign string or number.

Comment: @RobertWilliams - After all that, don't forget to take a look at the method with the `map` operator.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for the suggestion. Will surely read about `map` as well :)

Answer (score 1):

try following code snippet.

```
ngFor="let subject of subjects|async
```

**Update**

In your `ExaminerService` you should import `FirebaseListObservable` in order to define return type `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class ExaminerService{
     constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

    getBatchSubjects(batch){
        return this.db.list('/subjects');
    }

}
```

In your Component should look like this

```
export class ExaminerComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: any[];

  constructor(private examinerDb: ExaminerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.examinerDb.get().subscribe((snaps) => {
       this.selectedBatchData = snaps;
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: didn't work. ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: your method should return `get (): FirebaseListObservable<any[]>{
        return this.db.list('/subjects');
    }`

Comment: How can it work? You are not even extracting json from response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163116/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-robert-williams).

Answer (score 0):

Angular has pipe "keyvalue" which will let you parse your object into pairs like subject.key and subject.value